# How to connect to Mongo database locally using python

Tags: python, mongodb, ipython, pymongo

I am using ipython 2.7. I am creating database name enron in mongodb. I have tried to connect to this database locally but the following error occurred - how do I fix it?

this my code:

```
import json
import pymongo  # pip install pymongo
from bson import json_util 
from pymongo import MongoClient# Comes with pymongo
conn = pymongo.Connection('mongodb://user:user123@localhost27017.mongolab.com:33499/enron')
client = MongoClient()
```

error:

```
ConnectionFailure: could not connect to localhost:27017: [Errno 10061] No connection     could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this [PyMongo Connection](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#making-a-connection-with-mongoclient) to connect and Connection is [deprecated](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/connection.html)

Comment: link is outdated

Answer (score 19):

Below are commands to create connection and query

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('hostname', 27017)
db = client.database_name
collection = db.collection_name
collection.find_one({"name":"name1"})
```

Answer (score 6):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import json_util


MONGODB_HOST = 'localhost'
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
DB_NAME = 'Your DB name'
COLLECTION_NAME = 'collectionname'

@app.route("/")
def getDatas():
    connection = MongoClient(MONGODB_HOST, MONGODB_PORT)
    collection = connection[DB_NAME][COLLECTION_NAME]
    projects = collection.find()
    json_projects = []
    for project in projects:
        json_projects.append(project)
    json_projects = json.dumps(json_projects, default=json_util.default)
    connection.close()
    return json_projects

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000,debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

### Solution worked for me

```
#!pip install pymysql

import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

import MySQLdb

#!pip install pymongo
import pymongo
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient


import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient
# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017, maxPoolSize=50)
client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017, maxPoolSize=50)
db = client.mydb
collection = db.angel
data = pd.DataFrame(list(collection.find()))
```

---

```
data

'''
Address City    Name    State   ZIP _id
0   123 Main St Whereverville   Jane Doe    CA  90210   5af03bfa8ca570abf4a2f76c
1   555 Broadway Ave    New York    John Doe    NY  10010   5af03bfa8ca570abf4a2f76d
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command from command line in mongo installtion directory.

...>mongo>...>bin>

mongod --dbpath data/db (here data/db is a path where your database)

Answer (score 0):

A derivation of @amit above, I use this to quickly test a mongodb connection:

```
# pip install pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('mongodb://user:password@host:port/database')

for db in client.list_databases():
    print(db)
```

Comment: Where to find the "user" and "password" parameters for a localhost installation?